# Is there any IDE that has code-hinting for CakePHP or any code-hinting package that can be installed somehow?

Tags: cakephp, intellisense, code-hinting

Question says it all...

Comment: As a side note, if you'd like to see excellent CakePHP support in an excellent IDE, please register and vote for "the cause" here: http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=140918 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this functionality in Netbeans as described in this article from the bakery.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/model-based-code-insight-and-completion-in-netbeans

You can also do the same thing in Eclipse PDT or Aptana.

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/code-completion-for-cakephp-in-eclipse

All of these IDEs are free. Although they are both

---

## Updating

Now [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) has a plugin for CakePHP.

Comment: I just installed Aptana and I'm finding it extremely useful!

Comment: I like Aptana too. The css editor is pretty nifty on Aptana too. The only editor I like better is Textmate.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an IDE, but if you are a textmate user, then there is a bundle for CakePHP: http://thechaw.com/cakephp_tmbundle

Answer (score 1):

[Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) has a [CakePHP addon](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920121658/http://community.activestate.com/node/2794) and a [macro to ease MVC navigation](https://web.archive.org/web/20121227232831/http://community.activestate.com:80/forum/cakephp-toggle-eases-cakephp-navigation).

It is built on the Mozilla code base so is similarly extensible through addons, has equivalent memory consumption/speeds, and is licensed under the same terms.

Nearly forgot to mention, it is also [cross-platform](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/).

Answer (score 1):

PHPed by Nusphere works great. They've even posted an [excellent article](http://www.nusphere.com/php/cakephp.htm) to help get it all set up.